# I need something to create users in FileZilla (XML settings file) from the command-line

Tags: xml, command-line, command-line-arguments, filezilla

I'll be honest, I'm looking for some major help here. I need an application that will create user/pwd/foldername for FileZilla Server (it's an XML settings file), but that can be fired from the command-line, as it will take these variables (and be launched) from another application. An application I don't have code access to, btw. I'm not a developer, but I'm prepared to have a go with this, if someone can help me (albeit with MOST of it!).

If someone has already done this, then happy day!

Comment: If you cannot write this program yourself, then this question is not on topic for this website, you must be able to do it yourself.  I have to downvote your question for that reason.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but I wanted to manage users in .Net. I found this library that helped me a lot.

https://github.com/PolarbearDK/Miracle.FileZilla.Api

I hope it could help you too.

Answer (score 0):

I used VBScript - full script posted [here](http://allpinkynobrain.wordpress.com/2012/07/13/creating-filezilla-user-via-vbscript-in-a-troll-averse-world/), if anyone else needs help.